# Get contents of local folder in javascript (or ASP.NET VB)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, directory, local

Is it possible for a webpage to popup a open folder dialog, ask the user to select a folder, then show the contents of that folder in a list(or something) in the webpage. 
It won't write to the files, only read them.
The webpage is hosted remotely.

Jonathan

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support? JavaScript does not provide any standardized means for accessing the file system. (And that's on purpose, for security reasons. You wouldn't want any odd website to be able to browse around in your files, would you?). However, there are browser-specific ways to get to the file system (e.g. via an ActiveX object with IE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word... No.

Requiring an ActiveX plug-in for your application is an invitation to utter failure.  Unless you are writing a very target-specific app for an intranet where you control the client configuration, this is just a horrible idea.

There are strict limitations on what a web-based application can do, and this is one of them.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps there's a way to do it with a standard file upload dialog?  Or WebDAV?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this small piece of code that shows a list of files given a folder name. It is written using VBScript so will work only on IE and FireFox(and maybe only on windows). But it is worth a look

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='VBSCRIPT'>
Sub showfiles()
On Error Resume Next
Dim fso, folder, files, sFolder, path

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = Document.getElementById("fdr").value
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
Set files = folder.Files

For each folderIdx In files
mydiv.innerhtml=mydiv.innerhtml & "<BR/> " & folderIdx.Name
Next
end sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT id="fdr" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="C:\" />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ONCLICK="showfiles()" value="show files" />
<DIV id="mydiv"></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: As far as I know this would only work if the user double clicked on the .html file which was saved on their local computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Signed Java Applet, it is a fairly common solution. It works across browsers and platforms. All the user would have to do accept your certificate once and have the java runtime installed.

Alternatively you can write a browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** :- Have a look at [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201). May be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It'll make you (or your usesr) jump through a thousand hoops, but the ActiveX File System Object can possibly be used to do what you want...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx696eh%28VS.85%29.aspx

edit -- added "possibly"

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with JavaScript, as it has no way of working with the operating system.

There *is*, however, a way to do it with VBScript (ASP.NET), but IE will throw a security warning to the user before allowing the code to execute **only if** their security level is less than Medium-Low.

If you're trying to access local files over the Internet, your best bet (outside of finding a vulnerability and getting access that way, i.e. the bad way) is by using Java or Flash.

If you still want the code (for ASP/VBscript):

`Dim FileSystem

Set FileSystem = GetObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgBox("Error setting FileSystem object; check WSH version.")

    WScript.Quit(0)

End If



Dim Folder

Set Folder = FileSystem.GetFolder("folder_name")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgBox("Error getting folder.")

    WScript.Quit(1)

End If`

-Carlos Nunez